# Holder function and weak derivatives

Tags: integration, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, holder-spaces

Let $B_1$ the $n$-dimensional unit ball and $u\in C^{0,\alpha}(B_1)$ be an $\alpha$-Holder continuous function, for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$, such that $u(0)=0$. Is it true that
$$
\int_{B_{1/2}} |x \cdot \nabla u| \,\mathrm{d}x < + \infty?
$$
I have no clue about this question I found also some difficulties in the construction of a possible counter-example. I initially thought that the hyphotesi $u\in C^{0,\alpha}(B_1)$ was not enough to ensure the bound of the integral but it was necessary to have some sort of non-degeneracy like
$$
1/c\leq \mbox{sup}\left\{\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha},x,y\in B_{1/2},x\neq y\right\}\leq c,
$$
for some $c>1$.

Comment: how do you make sense of the integrand if $\nabla u$ is only a distribution?

Comment: to the deleted comment; perhaps the OP should mention the dimension of the space